# Terraform - share outputs between folders

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, terraform

I am having the following folder structure for terraform:

terraform

```
--dev
----- main.tf
----- s3
--------- main.tf
--------- s3_create_bucket_1.tf
----- lambda 
---------- main.tf
---------- create_lambda_1.tf
```

In create_lambda_1.tf I can use outputs of resources created in the root folder (dev). However, I wonder how can I use an output created in the folder s3 (that is at the same level as lambda)?

Or more generally, I understand that best practices suggest using folders to structure the code. But I dont find anywhere information about how one can pass information between the folders? (In the example above how can I dynamically get the .arn of the bucket created in the s3 folder)

Thanks in advance.

/Luminita

Comment: Have you come across data sources yet? You would want the [`aws_s3_bucket`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/s3_bucket) data source which allows you to look up the ARN given a bucket name.

Answer (score 0):

Hello forget about the folders if you create an output it will be saved in the tfstate, you can use

`data "terraform_remote_state"`

here's a [ref](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html)

and you can use an output anywhere you want example :

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "vpc" {
 ...
}

resource "aws_instance" "foo" {
  # ...
  subnet_id = data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.subnet_id
}
```

Comment: Please stop recommending using the remote state data source when there are native data sources (such as the `aws_s3_bucket` data source in this case) available. Remote state was useful before the advent of these but that's now more than 4 years ago and remote state as a data source is more complicated to manage than the direct native data sources. It _can_ be useful in the rare cases you need to share data between Terraform runs that aren't exposed by a data source but these are very limited.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR  i understand your feeling about the remote state but you are speaking as if  only the tfstate file in s3 bucket there is  at lease 6 ways to use tfstate be more accurate please .what if i use http as a backend for my tfstate would aws_s3_bucket work ? 
and just for information me too i don't use remote state i use terragrunt dependencies.
We can use multiple backend for the tfstate your  suggestion only work with 1 specific  case :)

Comment: The remote state is irrelevant if you use the `aws_s3_bucket` data source as it just runs the `HeadBucket` API call to check for that information. So you don't need to be using remote state at all (this is a bad idea) or you can use any backend as it's not linked to this at all.

Comment: I am sorry i was speaking generally i thought you meant getting the tfstate itselt from datasource aws s3 bucket. anyway i get what you are trying to say. like i said maybe managing remote tf state is hard for some people. my point of view is maybe managing  tfstate is hard but managing read access on tfstates are easier than manging the read acess to all the resources you want to pass by datasource  and  when you said "that aren't exposed by a data source but these are very limited" i think you are speaking about AWS. that's not the same on the other providers.

Comment: Guys, thanks for all the answers! I am however a beginner in terraform and it is not easy to follow your discussions here.

Comment: Montassar - thanks for the tip, it works fine to use outputs & the remote state. 
@ydaetskcoR - I dont completely follow your explanation. If I have two folders, for example s3/ where an s3 bucket is created, then a folder called lambda/ where I need to use the s3 bucket created. How can I get the arn of the bucket in the lambda folder (without creating dependencies such as if one changes the resource in s3, one doesnt need to change everywhere where the resource is used)?

Comment: changing a resource in s3 doesn't change the s3 arn since it's unique to the bucket  you can use either  an output in s3 folder then use  remote state to get it in lambda folder or you can use  data aws_s3_bucket like @yadetskcoR suggested